# How to do math operations with the SQL OVER() command on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We are trying to do a math operation with the SQL OVER() command.

This is the kind of query we would like to run...

```
SELECT SurvivedCount/(SUM(SurvivedCount) OVER()) AS PercentSurvived
```

...but it gives this error:

```
Encountered " "OVER" "OVER "" at line 2, column 50. Was expecting: ")" ...
```

Apart from splitting this into a two stage SQL sub-select, is there any way to do math with the OVER() operation on Google BigQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable standard SQL. Legacy SQL is enabled by default.

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  tmp AS (
  SELECT
    10 AS SurvivedCount,
    'foo' AS a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    20 AS SurvivedCount,
    'foo' AS b)
SELECT
  SurvivedCount,
  SurvivedCount/(SUM(SurvivedCount) OVER()) AS PercentSurvived
FROM
  tmp
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: Specifically, if I remember correctly, there is a parsing issue with parentheses around analytic functions using legacy SQL but it should work fine using standard SQL.